# Select a subset of matched content?

Tags: azure-cognitive-search

I'm using search to index PDFs stored in Azure blob containers.  I'd like to return approximately 500-1000 characters of matched text from my searched content so I can highlight this to a user in my web app.  The content itself may be up to 200 000 characters which is too large to send over the network.  Is it possible to do a substring on a part of the matched content on the server side before sending results to the client?  I'm using SearchParameteres to filter matched data, identify facets, and select specific fields to return as follows:

```
`SearchParameters sp = new SearchParameters()
{
    SearchMode = SearchMode.Any,
    Top = 10,
    Skip = currentPage - 1,
    // select specific fields
    Select = new List<String>() {"metadata_storage_path", "PubYear", "PubMonth", "PubDay", "NewspaperName", "content"},
    IncludeTotalResultCount = true,
    // Add facets
    Facets = new List<String>() { "PubYear", "PubMonth", "PubDay", "NewspaperName" },
};`
```

Tks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The closest I can think of is using the hit highlighting API ->
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/searchservice/search-documents#highlightstring-optional
which will return a few text fragments that matches your query for each document. You currently cannot configure the size of the text fragments, but each text fragments should at least include the full sentence where they are found.

Comment: Perfect.  Thank you.